# Access database based on form value

Tags: php, sql, loops, associative-array

So I created an array, and placed the array values into a form using foreach (at the bottom of the code).

```
<html>
<script>
function showUser(str) 
{
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//place Last Name in array
$sql="SELECT Lname FROM Customers";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$lnames=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_free_result($result);

foreach($lnames as $x) {
    $a[] = $x['Lname'];
}

echo 
"<select>";
foreach($a as $val => $option) 
{
    echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$option.'</option>'; 
}
"</select>";

?>
```

I want to know if is possible to run the showUser function in the  by making the  use "onchange". I tried using:

```
echo 
"<select onchange="showUser(this.value)">";

foreach($a as $val => $option) 
{
    echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$option.'</option>'; 
}
"</select>";
```

But it states there's an error regarding unexpected showUser, syntax error, missing ; or ,. I want to allow the user to choose a option, and load the corresponding data entry, but this will not allow it.

Comment: What's the problem that you are having? Did you even try running this code? And I can see hundreds of question in this community, asking about very similar issues..

Answer (score 0):

Try out below corrections in your current code

```
mysqli_free_result($result); /* don't use `$lnames` here */

foreach($lnames as $x) { /* $x is row, can have multiple columns */
    echo $x['Lname'],'<br/>'; /* use column name */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, your question is asked many times by the others, and there are plenty of answers. I'd like to take this chance to help you understand some concepts that you seem to be missing, based on how your wrote your code.

```
$sql="SELECT Lname FROM Customers";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

It's a common misconception that mysqli_query returns a result. Even more "experienced" programmers sometimes use the variable $res, thinking it's a result. In fact it is a *cursor*, or a *pointer* to the record set that's returned. Hence, in some documentations, the variable $rs instead of $res. (Naming doesn't matter to machines, but they do help you understand the data flow.)

Then you wrote this:

```
$lnames=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

At this point, your $lnames contains all the rows of the result. It's better to name it $records. You may view the values of this variable:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($records); echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to print out the last name of each record, use this loop:

```
foreach ($records as $record){
    echo $record['Lname'].'<br>';
}
```

Note the capitalized L, as that's how it is in your query.

Also fetch_all is only available with the mysqlnd package. You might want to get into the habit of loop through the record set:

```
while ($myrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
  echo $myrow['Lname'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: That line was in OP's code, but not mine. Also the allocated resources are freed implicitly any way at the end of a page rendering.